# Regex - Only ONE special char

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I'm currently working with a regex that I created for a password.

It have to respect this conditions :

- 8 characters
- At least one MAJ (A-Z)
- At least one min (a-z)
- At least one digit (0-9)
- One special char from the following : .,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?-]/\
- Prohibit the following characters : <>`

**Here is the regex :**

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\])(?!.*[<>`]).{8}
```

All works fine, but now, I want it to accept **only ONE special char**.

I searched and tried a lot of things (with {1} at the end of the group for example), but it doesn't work at all ! Results like **Aa1;;aaa** are still matching..

Could someone tell me how can I do that ?

Comment: **On a side note:** Please don't restrict your users like this. Some users don't like being forced to use impossible to remmember passwords. You can add a "your password is weak" warning if you want, but prohibiting it is just frustrating. (Also, saying a password like "somelargesentencethatishardtobruteforce" is weak is just dumb).

Comment: Restricting users like this **reduce** security because it reject strong passwords and makes passwords generators hard to use.

Comment: That is a long and horrible regex. Have you considered applying the validation criteria separately, so you have at least a chance of ever understanding it when you come back to it in 6 months?

Comment: Maybe this would be shorter: `(?=[^\W_]*[\W_][^\W_]*$)`.. But I would highly recommend to separate your regex, then you can alert users why their password fails (Ex: `You need at least one digit`, `There can not be two or more special letters`, `...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

`` ^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*[<>`])([^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*)[.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\](?1)$ ``

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qR3vH5/1)

It check the length with a lookahead, then makes sure it has only one special char, with something different before and after it

`(?1)` is a reference to the 1st group pattern, you can replace it with `[^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*` If you wish or not supported by your tool

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qR3vH5/2)

Or, while preserving your original syntax:

`` (?=.*[A-Z])
(?=.*[a-z])
(?=.*[0-9])
(?!.*[<>`])
(?=[^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*
   [.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]
   [^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*$
)
.{8}$ ``

Here's the compacted version: `` (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*[<>`])(?=[^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*[.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\][^.,:;'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\]*$).{8}$ ``

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qR3vH5/4)

Comment: I think that this is a really good example of why regex is very powerful, but shouldn't be used for every job!

Comment: @Sobrique It answers the OP's question indeed, but as comments said above: restricting a psw that much is a bad idea; I had the experience myself of being stuck at a registration page with no idea what's wrong => it was the psw :S

Comment: Agreed - it does. And regex is a very powerful tool. It's just the wrong one (in my opinion) for this particular job

Comment: Thanx all of you for the answers, I appreciate it ! And thx to Enissay, I will take your code, it made the job ! I didn't say it at the beggining but that regex will be use for an intern website, and only by AD users of the company to change their passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Really - I wouldn't do this. First off - fussy password rules aren't a good idea. They reduce security, because they reduce the keyspace.

But more fundamentally - one regex to rule them all is not a good design strategy. Your existing regex is sufficiently long and complicated that a maintenance programmer is going to have to spend a while to figure out what it does, and if it changes in future.... you'll go through this headache all over again.

So I'm going to offer an alternative - break apart your regex, apply the validation criteria separately, and give messages to say why it failed. Something like this (implemented in whatever language you're using):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my $fail = 0; 
    print "Testing: \"$_\"\n"; 

    if (not m/.{8}/) { 
        print "Rejected because less than 8 chars\n"; 
        $fail++;
    }
    if ( not m/[A-Z]/ ) { 
         print "Rejected - needs at least one upper case character\n";
         $fail++;
    }
    if ( not m/\d/ ) { 
        print "Rejected - needs at least one digit\n"; 
         $fail++;
    }
    if ( my @matches =  m/([.,:;\'!@#$%^&*_+=|(){}[?\-\]\/\\])/g ) {
        if ( @matches != 1 ) { 
                print "Rejected - exactly one special character, not more\n";
                $fail++; 
        }
    } 
    else {
        print "Rejected - needs a special character\n";
        $fail++; 
    }
    if ( m/[\<\>\`]/ ) { 
        print "Rejected - \"<>`\" not permited\n";
        $fail++; 
    }
    if ( not $fail ) { 
        print "$_ is OK\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
Fish1234!
!!moooMoo33
helloMum
```

This gives:

```
Testing: "Fish1234!"
Fish1234! is OK
Testing: "!!moooMoo33"
Rejected - exactly one special character, not more
Testing: "helloMum"
Rejected - needs at least one digit
Rejected - needs a special character
```

(Although I'll note - Fish1234! isn't exactly a robust password, even if it does pass your rules)